# d3.js les miserables matrix doesn't show

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have got myself a little bit stuck and I would like your help... 
I have tried the example of *les miserables* with a [new json file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mdv7jtkw32rnf5/miserables.json) 
for a project I am doing in topic detection, but nothing appears on screen while with [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sqrik7y66h6v84/miserablesok.json) everything works ok!
I am new to javascript and I can't seem to find where the problem is... 
If someone has any idea why the matrix won't show...

Now I see in console the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'z' of undefined

Does anybody know what that means?

Comment: Are you trying to load the data from a different domain? Cross-origin policy problems would be one thing to check. Also, look in your JS console - what errors do you see? Finally, you might be better off with Gists or Pastebin or something similar, rather than DropBox, for sharing files like this on SO.

Comment: No, i am loading data from the same directory. And the weird part is, i dont see any error in my console, so i am guessing there's something wrong with the json file... Thank you for your suggestions, i tried dropbox but i can see your point.

Comment: Forgot to mention that jsonlint shows that json file is valid

Comment: your links are broken